# How to read a value of type Long from a application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I am working with redis cache. I have in my code

Where the time is hardcoded

```
@RedisHash(timeToLive=60)
```

In applications.yml  File I would like to add the following

```
throttle: 
  cache: 
    rate: 60
```

So I can have the following

```
@RedisHash(timeToLive="${throttle.cache.rate}")
```

But this failed with Type mismatch cannot convert from String to Long. So I tried

```
@RedisHash(timeToLive="#{new Long(}'${throttle.cache.rate}')")
```

But still failing with Type mismatch cannot convert from String to Long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, that is not possible. Why? Because the value for an annotation must be a compile-time constant. All the compiler knows at compile time is that you are passing a `String` to a property that only accepts `long`.

It will only be a `long` when you run your Spring application but that is too late because the compiler does not know that.

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling this would be the case. Scheduling gets around this by adding a value for String. I was hoping there would be a similar for Redis.

Comment: Unfortunately no, not yet at least. If you feel like, consider upvoting my answer and accepting it so that it can be ”closed” and others can benefit from it easily ;) Thanks!